# DOCTRINE - Number of query result change for no apparent reason

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine

i'm facing a strange problem: here is the deal.

When i am doing this:

```
$query = $this->createQueryBuilder('s')
            ->select('s')
            ->leftJoin('s.Cluster', 'u')
            ->where('u.id = 15')
            ->orWhere('u.id=37')
            ->getQuery()
            ->getResult();
var_dump(count($query));
```

the output is `2`

but if i do :

```
$query = $this->createQueryBuilder('s')
            ->select('s')
            ->leftJoin('s.Cluster', 'u')
            ->where('u.id = 15')
            ->orWhere('u.id=37');
$query
            ->getQuery()
            ->getResult();
var_dump(count($query));
```

the output is `1`.. can someone explain? i don't understand where it could come from

Comment: The `$query` variable is different in each case. In the first, it's the results, in the second, it's the query object.

Comment: @JonStirling wow i'm so surprised... having my head in this i coudn't even notice this detail.. And it must've looked pretty obvious for you... Thank you for your help

Comment: No worries. Have a break, have a kit-kat :)

Comment: Can you explain in a little more detail what is going on here? Thanks

Comment: @JacekDziurdzikowski  oh in fact in the first part, i'm counting the number of results (stored in the `$query` variable). But in the second part, as i'm not doing `$query=$query->getQuery()->getResult()`, but just `$query->getQuery()->getResult()`, the results aren't stored in the variable `$query`. So in the second case `$query` represents the query itself

Comment: Right, I didn't notice that as well :) Thanks!

Comment: one is the result, the other one seems the queryBuilder object lol .It seems you worked for arround 10 h :p hhh